# How do I turn the outputs of a function into a list?

Tags: list, prolog

I have a function that outputs names that fit a specific constraint.  This function is fine.

But I need to use that function to make another function that turns the outputs of the former function into a list.  Being a complete beginner with Prolog, I have no clue how to do this.

My problem is that I don't know how to iterate over the outputs to append it to an accumulator.  The function which outputs names does so, then I press ";" or SPACE and it outputs the next answer until it's out of answers.  I figure this means I have to make multiple calls to the function then append it.  But I don't know how many times I need to call it, since I can't iterate over it like a list with [Head|Tail].

Here's what I have so far(although it's probably wrong):

```
%p1(L,X) determines if chemicals in List X are in any of the products and stores those        products in L
p1(L,X) :- p1_helper(L,X,[]).
p1_helper(L,X,Acc) :- has_chemicals(A,X),append(Acc,[A],K),L=K, p1_helper(L,X,K).
```

function that outputs names with query has_chemicals(X,[List of Chemicals]).:

```
%has_chemicals(X,Is) determines if the chemicals in List Is are in the chemical list of X.
has_chemicals(X,Is) :- chemicals(X,Y), hc(Y,Is).
%hc(X,Y) determines if elements of Y are in elements of X.
hc(Y,[]).
hc(Y,[C|D]) :- isin(C,Y), hc(Y,D).
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `isin` predicate can be replaced with `member/2`

Comment: It's an useful convention to place 'input' arguments before 'output'

Answer (score 3):

> But I need to use that function to make another function that turns the outputs of the former function into a list. Being a complete beginner with Prolog, I have no clue how to do this.

[`findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3):
    Creates a list of the instantiations `Template` gets successively on backtracking over `Goal` and unifies the result with `Bag`.

For example, how to collect all odd numbers from 1 to 15:

```
odd( X ) :-
    X rem 2 =:= 1.
```

We can get all that odds one-by-one.

```
?- between( 1, 15, X ), odd( X ).
X = 1 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 9 ;
X = 11 ;
X = 13 ;
X = 15.
```

And we can collect them into a list:

```
?- findall(X, (between( 1, 15, X ), odd( X )), List).
List = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15].
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a way to capture the output of isin/2. Then you can use the builtin [with_output_to/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2), and combine it with findall/3, as suggested by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to visit [this page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.28%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29) especially if you use swi-prolog.

There are 4 predicates that do what you want : `findall/3`, `findall/4`, `bagof/3` and `setof/3`.

To summarize, here is the test predicate I'll be working with :

```
test(0, 3).
test(1, 3).
test(2, 5).
test(3, 4).
```

First, the simplest, findall/3 and findall/4 :

```
?- findall(C, test(X, C), Cs).
Cs = [3, 3, 5, 4].

?- findall(C, test(X, C), Cs, TailCs).
Cs = [3, 3, 5, 4|TailCs].
```

They just return all the alternatives, with duplicates, without sorting, without binding the other free variables, as a normal list for `findall/3` and difference list for `findall/4`. both `findall`s predicates succeed when the list is empty.

Then, bagof. Basically, `bagof/3` works as `findall/3` but binds free variables. That means that the same query than above but with `bagof/3` returns :

```
?- bagof(C, test(X, C), Cs).
X = 0,
Cs = [3] ;
X = 1,
Cs = [3] ;
X = 2,
Cs = [5] ;
X = 3,
Cs = [4].
```

By telling `bagof/3` not to bind all the free variables, you obtain `findall/3` :

```
?- bagof(C, X^test(X, C), Cs).
Cs = [3, 3, 5, 4].
```

Still you have to note that `bagof/3` fails when the result is empty, where `findall/3` doesn't.

Finally, `setof/3`. It's basically `bagof/3` but with the results sorted and no duplicates :

```
?- setof(C, X^test(X, C), Cs).
Cs = [3, 4, 5].
```

Comment: your description of `bagof/3` and `setof/3` needs some further elaboration for the case of variables.  See [this recent thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8394843/772868) on how things go wrong with `findall/3`.