# Permutation Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

I am trying to make a list*list of all permutations from 1 to N

Example: perm(3, X). ->  X = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

I am instead getting

X = [1, 2, 3]

X = [1, 3, 2]

X = [2, 1, 3]

X = [2, 3, 1]

X = [3, 1, 2]

X = [3, 2, 1]

and having to keep hitting next. My question is how would I put all values of X into a list like the example run that I want. Here is my existing code:

```
permHelp([],[]).
permHelp(List,[H|Finish]):-delete(H,List,Rest),permHelp(Rest,Finish).

delete(X,[X|T],T).
delete(X,[H|T],[H|NT]):-delete(X,T,NT).

createList(0, L, L) :- !.
createList(N, R, L) :- N > 0, N1 is N-1, createList(N1, [N|R], L).

perm(N, X):- createList(N, [], L), permHelp(L, X).
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8394843/772868)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permute into a list SWI-Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385423/permute-into-a-list-swi-prolog)

Comment: @false You found a pretty close duplicate. I am voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: OK. Still, this question is one of the better ones.

Comment: @false but I want to use my code here and list all into a single list instead of using the built-in permutation predicate

Comment: @Michael: `list_allperms/2` relates a list and all its permutations.

Answer (score 1):

```
perm(N, X):-
   createList(N, [], L),
   list_allperms(L, X).
```

With [`list_allperms/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8394843/772868) defined in another answer.

What you call `permHelp` should rather be called `permutation`.