# SICStus Prolog: How to permute the list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Tags: list, prolog, permutation, clpfd

I am new to Prolog and I'm trying out list permutation predicates.

Most of them take two arguments (e.g., `permutation/2`).

I'm looking to create one which only takes one argument (list) and also finds out if the list has exactly 10 elements.

So for example:

```
| ?- permutation([7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9]).
yes

| ?- permutation(X).
X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
...      

| ?- permutation([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]).
A = 0
B = 1
C = 2 
...
J = 9 ;
```

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutation Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350677/permutation-prolog)

Comment: Hmm i dont think so, since im asking about permutation/1 and not permutation/2

Comment: just define permutation10(X) :- permutation(10, X) . Then you can call permutation10([7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9]), permutation10(X), or permutation10([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]), etc..

Comment: oh god, thats so obvious, thanks!

Comment: But you have to check whether it really works. It might still not work, depends on how exactly permutation/2 is implemented and what input/output modes it supports.

Comment: To determine if a list has 10 elements, you would just say, `length(List, 10).` which will be true if `List` has 10 elements. But if you want a predicate to determine if a list is a permutation of the values `0` through `9`, just define it using `permutation/2`: `permutation10(List) :- permutation([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], List).`

Comment: takeout(X,[X|R],R).  
takeout(X,[F |R],[F|S]) :- takeout(X,R,S).

perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y,W), takeout(X,Z,W).  
perm([],[]).

gen_perm(X) :- perm(X, Q), length(X, 10).

Comment: this is what i have right now. something is missing i guess

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If you have code, edit your question and put it there, properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Work smarter, not harder:
**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Using [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length), [`domain/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Membership-Constraints.html), [`all_different/1`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic_002dLogical-Constraints.html), and [`labeling/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Enumeration-Predicates.html) we define:

```
perm10(Zs) :-
   length(Zs,10),
   domain(Zs,0,9),
   all_different(Zs),
   labeling([],Zs).
```

Consider the goal `gen_perm([8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`.
We expect<sup>1</sup> it to fail, and, in fact, it **does**...

 ... **but** how much work is being performed executing above goal?

Let's measure runtimes<sup>2</sup> using [`call_time/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823841/4609915)!

```
?- use_module(library(between),[repeat/1]).
true.

?- _Zs = [8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], call_time((repeat(1000),gen_perm(_Zs);true),T_us).
T_us = 21940.

?- _Zs = [8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], call_time((repeat(1000),perm10(_Zs)  ;true),T_us).
T_us = 10.
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** There are only 8 different integers in the list, so it cannot be a permutation of all integers between 0 and 9.</sup>

<sup>**Footnote 2:** Using [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/) version 4.3.2, x86_64-linux-glibc2.12.</sup>

Comment: Even easier: perm10(Zs) :- sorting(Zs, _, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), labeling(Zs).`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the replies! This works:

```
takeout(X,[X|R],R).  
takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]) :-
   takeout(X,R,S).

perm([X|Y],Z) :-
   perm(Y,W),
   takeout(X,Z,W).
perm([],[]).

gen_perm(List) :-
   perm([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],List),
   length(List,10).
```

Comment: If `perm` works properly, then you shouldn't need `length(List, 10)` since `perm` shouldn't be generating a list `List` which only consists of elements from `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.