# Preserve clpfd constraint variable in findall

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to capture a constraint variable in `findall`. But on the other end I get independent copies of the variable:

```
?- X #> 1, findall(X, (true; true), Xs), X #< 100.
Xs = [_A, _B],
X in 2..99,
_B in 2..sup,
_A in 2..sup.
```

By looking at the code I would expect `_A = X` and `_B = X` instead. It seems the `findall` machinery makes copies of the captured variable.

I can achieve the desired result by iterating over a list, but that doesn't look like an idiomatic Prolog approach:

```
?- X #> 1, maplist({X}/[_,R]>>(R=X), [_,_], Xs), X #< 100.
Xs = [X, X],
X in 2..99.
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result with `findall`/clauses?

Comment: I think that is still an open problem in Prolog; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728942/

Comment: I view `findall` and e.g. `bagof` as far *stranger* in Prolog than iterating over a list (which is simple and clear). Here's the code for `bagof`: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/boot/bags.pl?show=src#bagof/3